"Negative time evidence" in the news - are they really observing causation backward in time?
There are many news about recent https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.03680 by Aephraim M. Steinberg group, e.g.:
https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/evidence-of-negative-time-found-in-quantum-physics-experiment/
https://www.independent.co.uk/tech/time-negative-quantum-physics-clock-b2621812.html
claiming observation of change of phase before the impulse - here is change of phase vs delay in nanosecond from the article, with clear response both before and after the impulse:

Why it doesn't allow to send information back in time?
It uses postselection as e.g. delayed choice quantum erasure, which forbids its application to send information backward in time there - is it also the case here?

Please do not link directly to PDF files. Always link to the article abstract. See https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11400/123208

From https://www.gregegan.net/APPLETS/20/20.html  "[...] a wave composed of a multitude of frequencies moving at different velocities – all less than or equal to c, the speed of light in a vacuum – can appear to have features moving faster than c. [...] This illusion of superluminal motion can only occur when the refractive index of the medium falls as the frequency of the light increases, a situation known as anomalous dispersion. If it falls rapidly enough, the group velocity – the speed at which the overall envelope of the wave seems to move – can even become negative".

What exactly is your question that is not already answered by the last few paragraphs of the Scientific American article? It explicitly says this does not yield FTL effects, and states "Even though the phenomenon is astonishing, it has no impact on our understanding of time itself"

@ACuriousMind, so why cannot we send information back by such test of phase change before impulse? Due to postselection?

That is a good question! The reports specifically indicate that there isn’t information transfer; I’d imagine that that implies that if you tried building a comms system with this effect, the signal and noise levels would be equal so you wouldn’t be able to get any information across (or better yet, other quantum effects happen to intervene in a perfect storm to prevent information transfer). In flat space, no information can be transferred faster than $299792458$ meters per second.

It's the same story as every AMO paper in Nature or Science these days. Actual QM is perfectly causal and evolves forward in time, just as expressed by the Schrodinger equation over 100 years ago. None of these experiments ever contradict that. However, there are overly confusing ways of talking about those results which contain unobservable elements that violate causality, change the past, or whatever else. In order to get a more flashy headline, ambitious AMO physicists intentionally frame their papers in this more confusing way.

That is why a lot of laypeople get the sense that "anything goes" in quantum mechanics. It's not actually true: the same old laws work perfectly, but there is a huge, multi-billion dollar research industry devoted to making QM sound as confusing as possible. Not everything goes in nature, but anything confusing enough goes into Nature.

Looking at the “weak values” in the middle of a post-selected experiment is known to give surprising results, and this experiment certainly bears this out!  One option would be to ignore these weak values as mere calculational steps which don’t mean anything.  But there’s a reasonable case to make that if we’re ever going to figure out a realistic account of what is happening (in space and time) in the middle of these experiments, that looking at the weak values is the best guide we’re going to get.  So I think it’s worth thinking this through a little more carefully, especially in light of these intriguing experimental results.
The first crucial point is that a “post-selection” at the end of an experiment is not an intervention.  It’s not a cause.  If I post-select on cases where I win a hand of blackjack, that doesn’t cause me to win that hand.  And if you don’t post-select, the average weak value in the past always looks normal.  So even if the weak values are representative of some deeper reality, there’s no possibility of a backward-time-signal here; there’s nothing you can do in the future to produce a measureable difference to the (average) weak value you can measure in the past.  If there’s any retrocausation going on, it’s necessarily at a hidden level.
That said, each experiment is not an average; any given run of the experiment is one individual case, and it would be nice to say that something particular happened in the middle.  Post-selection in this context raises the question: given that we see the photon transmitted, what can we infer just happened?  Apparently, what we can infer in this experiment is that (1) the photon moved through faster than it would have ordinarily done (as least as judged by the phase), and (2) the average number of excited atoms dropped below normal.  And we take this number to ordinarily be zero, so it seems to be dropping to a negative number! Is there any realistic (space and time-based) intermediate history in which both of these might make sense?
Maybe there is.  After all, the classical statement “there are no excited atoms” doesn’t port over to quantum theory very well.  Consider the more commonly discussed case where one has “zero photons” in some mode.  Quantum theory treats this “vacuum state” very differently from a state of nothing at all.  In quantum field theory, the vacuum state is still “something”.  Arguably, quantum theory can be viewed as saying that the classical analog of “zero photons” is really the case where you have a classical electromagnetic field with the energy of half a photon.  (This viewpoint is sometimes used to explain “spontaneous” emission as really being stimulated emission from this half-a-photon field.).
So let’s imagine that this strategy might work for the “zero excited atoms”.  Maybe, down at some wave-level where this makes sense, there really is some deeper reality where each ground-state atom secretly carries a partially-excited-mode that we can’t normally see (for the same reason we can’t see the half-photon in the vacuum state).  If you grant this step, I can describe a spacetime-based history that matches both (1) and (2) above.  It goes like this:
A photon approaches the atomic cloud.  Meanwhile, a bunch of atoms in the atomic cloud each give up a little bit of their “hidden excited states”, and they collectively emit a photon in the forward direction.  (The number of excited atoms has now dropped, not really below zero, but below what we normally take be to “zero excited atoms”, so it looks like a negative number.)  So now the ground-state of the atoms is extra populated, above what we normally take to be the baseline case.  Then, the original photon arrives in the cloud and is absorbed by those extra ground-state-atoms, returning them to their original “hidden excited state” level.  Everything is now back to normal, except the photon appears to travel a bit faster than it should have.
And there’s one more clue that something strange has happened, apart from the speed of the photon.  If you’re watching the atoms during this process (as the experiment does), it seems like the number of excited atoms has dropped to a negative number for a short period of time.  The big news here is that this now matches observations!  But, if you grant the above premise, this doesn’t mean there are negative numbers of atoms; it just has to drop below “normal”.  (Other “anomalous” weak values can perhaps be explained in a similar way.)
Evidently, even though the history I’m describing here is logically possible, it doesn’t seem like there’s any forward-causal story which could explain it.  If something like this story is going to result from some physical theory, it would have to be an “all at once” theory, explainable only by some all-at-once calculation such as a global action extremization.  That in turn would imply some sort of hidden retrocausality, but not the sort you could use to send a signal into the past, as noted above.
This account is, of course, quite handwaving and speculative.  But if you’re looking for an account in the middle of one run of this experiment, an account which matches the observations, we’re pretty much stuck with something like this.  No matter how strange it might seem, any alternate explanation might arguably be considered much stranger.  So I would not be in any way dismissive of this fantastic result – it might be telling us something very interesting indeed.

Hi Ken, indeed postselection might be the defense here as in delayed choice quantum erasure, however, why couldn't they e.g. arbitrarily increase efficiency of emitter and detector? Instead, I would say the impulse emitter, as lasers in STED microscopy ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STED_microscopy ) or Rabi cycle, causes both excitation and deexcitation of the target, which are CPT analogs, hence have opposite time delays: https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.15399

At its core, this experiment is measuring the group delay of a light pulse through a medium. For certain parameters of the pulse, that delay can be negative, and that's what was observed. But it's been well-known for a long time that, even in other situations where a negative group delay arises, this phenomenon can't be used for any kind of faster-than-light signalling. This is because even though the peak of the pulse gets advanced, no part of the advanced pulse arrives earlier than the earliest you could detect the pulse without the medium. There is just as much information in the leading tail of the pulse as there is in the peak; the advancement just amounts to a reshaping.

So why somebody measuring phase difference wouldn't get information by seeing change a few dozens of nanosecond earlier than impulse as in plots above?


Why it doesn't allow to send information back in time?

There's two different notions of what "back in time" means in this context.
The everyday notion of going back in time means the entire universe marches backwards in time whilst the person remains unaffected by this otherwise universal reversal, and can therefore observe the reversal and potentially intervene in a course of events of which they are already aware.
From this commonsense fantasy, and because the conceptual content of physics is often taught poorly, there is often a belief even amongst educated physicists that faster-than-light travel (if it were not impossible) implies this style of reversal.
There's actually no known mechanism by which a human (or any other thing) could put the entire universe into reverse gear, let alone to do so whilst sparing themselves solely. Where would the energy come from, and how would the causation propagate instantly to all places so as to reverse everything in the same lockstep as when it was progressing forward?
What spacetime geometry and other relevant parts of physics are generally concerned with, is analysing situations involving signalling through a medium. And if you were to travel faster than light, the effect on the universe would be very similar to travelling faster than sound, which is that the entire universe does not suddenly throw into reverse gear, but it is possible to receive signals about events again in reverse order, or (once you have slowed down again) observe events that have already happened (and of which you are already aware) again in normal order.
Some physicists have ideological views which make this analysis highly problematic for them, because it implies that the observation of signals is not all there is, and that there are instead a form of "hidden variables" which mean it's hypothetically possible for certain (faster-than-light) travellers to observe signals about events going backwards whilst events are "really" still progressing forwards.
There are other areas of physics vexed by this battle about the presence or not of "hidden variables" in the physical world, whose presence can only detected by inference from multiple different kinds of observations and from theorising about how different observations are reconciled into a coherent explanation, rather than directly and independently manipulated.

I think you are referring to presentism philosophy of time: evolving 3D solution.
Instead, e.g. general relativity works on spacetime shape: 4D solutions, special relativity says this 3D changes with observer velocity, QFT is CPT symmetric - modern physics requires eternalism/block universe philosophy of time ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eternalism_(philosophy_of_time) ) - 4D solutions we travel through.
There is no fundamental problem with causality loops in such 4D solutions, however, they need to be self-consistent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Novikov_self-consistency_principle

@JarekDuda, I don't doubt that GR uses a form of 4D geometry, but the use of this geometry as a tool is not inconsistent with presentism. As I say though, I think the real issue here is essentially the role of "hidden variables". If you accept that the rest of the universe has variables that would need to be manipulated in order to restore the past into the present (or said equivalently, to restore yourself to the environment of the past), then it is less obvious why any translations (even at superluminal speed) would universally influence these states. (1/2)

Incidentally, if you implement clocks in terms of a sound medium (by analogy to Einstein's light clock), then SR is required to analyse the signalling through that sound medium. If you also add in changes in the density of the sound medium, then GR is required to analyse signalling through that sound medium. The issue isn't that relativity is faulty or is inconsistent with anything. The issue is that, for ideological reasons, the physics community prefer certain additional (and completely auxiliary) assumptions about what relativity is describing. (2/2)

Steve, while general relativity explicitly works on 4D spacetime as kind of 4D jello optimizing action, QFT assumes Feynman ensemble among 4D diagrams (perturbative approximation) or field configurations (non-perturbative) - all explicitly work on 4D block universe/eternalism philosophy of time. Hypothetical sending information back would just add contributions/constraints to above action optimization/Feynman ensembles, optimizing all CTCs (closed timelike curves) to self-consistent. Fundamentally there is no problem e.g. with wormholes.

@JarekDuda, I'm not doubting that mainstream physics has "no problem" with a lot of sci-fi. But there's nothing about the formalism of relativity that is inconsistent with presentism. I understand the block universe concept that relativity uses, but I don't interpret it to mean the same things as you do. In particular, when things advance or retard in time in the 4D geometry, I don't interpret this to mean time travel or an alteration in the state of the present universe, I interpret it to mean a change in the arrival times of signals. (1/3)

Simplest analogy for this is when the pilot of aircraft can travel faster than sound, he can hear a thunderclap once, then race ahead of the sound wavefront using the FTS facility of the aircraft, and then hear the same thunderclap a second time. The second presentation of the same event to the pilot via the sound medium, doesn't mean he "travelled back in time" in the conventionally understood sense. He simply heard it twice (as distinct from it happening twice). (2/3)

This idea that things can really happen a different number of times than you observe them to happen, and that relativity models the happenings as EM-mediated observations or signals (not the happenings directly), is why I'm describing it as effectively a "hidden variables" issue, because I'm suggesting the existence of happenings as real things which are distinct from our observations of the happenings. And by implication, I'm saying what is real is also not independently observable (at least by any currently known method). (3/3)
